# Second derivative calculation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule, jacobian

Consider $\boldsymbol{\psi}(\boldsymbol{q})\in R^2$ is a function of vector $\boldsymbol{q}(t)\in R^3$ which is a function of time $t\in R^+$. The first time derivative of function $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ can be defined as following equation using chain rule:
$\dot{\boldsymbol{\psi}}=\frac{\partial{\boldsymbol{\psi}}}{\partial{\boldsymbol{q}}}\dot{q}$.
In this equation $\frac{\partial{\boldsymbol{\psi}}}{\partial{\boldsymbol{q}}}\in R^{2\times3}$ is the Jacobian matrix. How it is possible to define the second time derivative of $\ddot{\boldsymbol{\psi}}$ using chain rule? For example if the function $\psi$ and $q$ were scalars we could define its second derivative easily by the following equation
$\ddot{\psi}=\frac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{q^2}} \dot{q}^2+\frac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{q}}\ddot{q}$.
But what about this case? Is there any similar equation for vector forms of $\boldsymbol{\psi} \in R^2$ and $\boldsymbol{q}(t) \in R^3$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The question is edited

Answer (score 1):

You can derive needed identity for second derivative if you express matrix multiplication as summation.
Let
$q:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb R^3, \psi: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$. We have
\begin{align}
\frac {\operatorname d^2}{\operatorname d\! t^2} \psi(q(t)) &= 
\frac {\operatorname d}{\operatorname d\! t}\left(\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial q}\bigg|_{q(t)}\dot q(t)\right) \\
&= \frac {\operatorname d}{\operatorname d\! t}\left(
\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^3
\frac {\partial \psi^i}{\partial x^j}\bigg|_{q(t)}\dot q^j(t){\bf e}_i\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^3 \left(
\frac {\partial \psi^i}{\partial x^j}\bigg|_{q(t)}\ddot q^j(t)+\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{\partial^2 \psi^i}{\partial x^k\partial x^j}\bigg|_{q(t)}\dot q^k(t)\dot q^j(t)\right){\bf e}_i \\
&= \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q}\bigg|_{q(t)}\ddot q(t) + \sum_{i=1}^2 \dot q(t)^TH(\psi^i)|_{q(t)}\dot q(t) {\bf e}_i,
\end{align}
where $H(\psi^i)$ is the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $\psi^i$ component of $\psi$ function.

If you know what you are doing, you could shorten this notation and write

$$
\frac {\operatorname d^2}{\operatorname d\! t^2} \psi(q(t))
= 
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q}\ddot q(t) + \dot q(t)^TH(\psi)\dot q(t).$$

Comment: What is $\textbf{e}_i$ in the equation above?

Comment: That's standard basis in $\mathbb R^n$; in this case $(1, 0, 0)^T, (0, 1, 0)^T$ and $(0, 0, 1)^T$ respectively.

Comment: In the above equation, $i$ varies from 1 to 3 and $\psi_i$ is said to be the $i$-th component of $\psi$. However, the dimension of $\psi$ is $2 \times 1$. Is that a flaw in the equations above?

Comment: What do you mean? $\psi:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$, so $\psi = (\psi^1, \psi^2, \psi^3)^T$, where each $\psi^i$ takes 2 arguments.

Comment: I mean according to my question, $\psi$: R^3 -> R^2$

Comment: Oh, right, I misread it; but changes are cosmetic, just swap 2s and 3s around. I'll edit it out

Comment: Also about the last equation, the dimansion of the term $\dot{q}(t)^TH(\psi)\dot{q}(t)$ seems to be $1 \times 1$. However, I think it should be $2 \times 1$

Comment: That's why I said you could use it as a *shortened notation* if *you know what you are doing*; Hessian matrix is not typically defined for vector valued functions like $\psi$, but if it were, it would be rank 3 tensor instead of matrix. Then adequate multiplication would result in appropriate vector.